# Background rendering OS X

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, performance

Is there an effective way of running Blender Cycles rendering in the background without hogging all of my iMacs resources and making basic desktop usage (i.e. Web browsing) completely impractical?

I've tried setting the Threads down to 2 in Render>Performance. I'm working on a fairly new iMac 2015 version with an i7, 32GB RAM and a Radeon R9 GFX card. I'm rendering via the OpenCL GPU. I believe my professor has 4cores and 8 threads.

However as soon as I start rendering a still or animation the machine becomes sluggishly slow.

Comment: The problem is that you are GPU rendering. If you check Activity Monitor, I suspect you will see that your CPU is being used relatively little, especially with an i7 core. Whenever you GPU render, the computer has a hard time quickly updating the screen, since the GPU is rendering your image instead of your interface. If you switch to CPU rendering, it should speed up your computer's performance, but that probably isn't good for your rendertimes.

Comment: And most desktop CPUs don't have enough cooling to handle using all of the cores for very long.

Comment: @chicks That isn't true. Especially with a Mac, the cooling system is plenty for even 8-thread rendering. I've had my Mac rendering for 3+ days straight. As long as the computer isn't in a super stuffy place, the computer can take care of itself heat-wise.

Comment: On Pro Macs maybe, but on the Mac Mini or MacBook Pro it isn't so.  I'm doubtful about the iMac, but I don't have one to test.

Comment: @ScottMilner I have a hackintosh that has a slower i5 CPU but a separate Ati 660 GPU. So similarish specs. However when I render on there and set the threads down to 2x, I'm able to render in the background and use the GUI comfortably. Which seems odd to me.